# Showing JSON data from database to view

Tags: json, codeigniter, foreach

This is an example of my table product and category in database:

tbl_categories

```
 |id_category | name........| slug........|

 |1...........| Hanger .....| hanger .....|
 |2...........| Lamp .......| lamp .......|
 |3...........| Merchandise | merchandise |
 |4...........| Storage ....| storage ....|
```

tbl_products

```
id_products | id_category | name .....| slug .....| images

1 ..........| 1 ..........| Hanger asd| hanger-asd|json
2 ..........| 1 ..........| Hanger asd| hanger-dsa|json
3 ..........| 1 ..........| Hanger asd| hanger-das|json
4 ..........| 1 ..........| Hanger asd| hanger-sad|json
```

where the content of images is json_encoded like this one:

id_product : 1

```
{
    "7b8d9fbfe384b1b6e4cfb0da473df8e5": {
        "alt": "jhonson hanger", 
        "caption": "", 
        "filename": "7b8d9fbfe384b1b6e4cfb0da473df8e5.jpg", 
        "primary": true
    }, 
    "f7d225c85590012f91bad32dd8adaa3d": {
        "alt": "jhonson hanger", 
        "caption": "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum dolor siamet ameticioud", 
        "filename": "f7d225c85590012f91bad32dd8adaa3d.jpg"
    }
}
```

etc.

First thing I want is to get every product to be shown on my ecommerce product page, so in my controller products:

```
function index()
{
    $data = array(
        "keyword" => "sadasdasd",
        "description" => "asdasdasd",
        "content" => "product",
        "title" => "BALOK Official :: Product"
    );
    $products = $this->model_product->get_all_products();
    $data['products'] = $products;

    $this->load->view("product", $data);
}
```

in my model_product:

```
function get_all_products()
{
    $this->db->select
    ("
        tbl_product.name AS prod_name,
        images,
        tbl_product.slug AS prod_slug,
        tbl_categories.slug AS cat_slug
    ");
    $this->db->from("tbl_products");
    $this->db->join("tbl_categories", "tbl_categories.id_category = tbl_product.id_category");
    $this->db->order_by("prod_name", "ASC");
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How to display product name, prod_slug, cat_slug and **only one** `images['filename]` for every product in my view, and if **"primary = true"** than show the primary image else show the first images. example in array maybe `images[0];`.

I have checked the data from fields images with this code:

```
foreach ($products as $prod)
{
    $prod->images = json_decode($prod->images);
    print_r($prod->images);
}
```

and that shows `stdClass` Object like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [43f8cd2ba0fcb96453b43b36b6a4f759] => stdClass Object
    (
        [filename] => 43f8cd2ba0fcb96453b43b36b6a4f759.jpg
        [alt] =>
        [caption] =>
        [primary] => 1
    )
)
stdClass Object
(
    [f7d225c85590012f91bad32dd8adaa3d] => stdClass Object
        (
            [filename] => f7d225c85590012f91bad32dd8adaa3d.jpg
            [alt] => jhonson hanger
            [caption] => lorem ipsum lorem ipsum dolor siamet ameticioud
            [primary] => 1
        )
    [7b8d9fbfe384b1b6e4cfb0da473df8e5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [filename] => 7b8d9fbfe384b1b6e4cfb0da473df8e5.jpg
        [alt] => jhonson hanger
        [caption] =>
    )
)
stdClass Object
(
    [29c2100ff85ec538e17c6d68fafbd43d] => stdClass Object
        (
            [filename] => 29c2100ff85ec538e17c6d68fafbd43d.jpg
            [alt] =>
            [caption] =>
            [primary] => 1
        )
    [8d4ecb9c4dc369febe70019586f3d570] => stdClass Object
    (
        [filename] => 8d4ecb9c4dc369febe70019586f3d570.jpg
        [alt] =>
        [caption] =>
    )
    [dc4358c470c33f20206afc180a28ae5b] => stdClass Object
        (
            [filename] => dc4358c470c33f20206afc180a28ae5b.jpg
            [alt] =>
            [caption] =>
        )
)
```

That stdobject makes me confused.

update.
in view i write this:

```
foreach ($products as $prod)
{
  echo $prod->prod_name.' - '.$prod->prod_slug.' - '.$prod->cat_slug.'<br>';
}
```

it success display what i want;

Book Cabinets Wood - book-cabinets-wood - storage
Brand New Hanger Jhonson - brand-new-hanger-jhonson - hanger
Flash Wood - flash-wood - merchandise
Gantungan baju dari kayu - gantungan-baju-dari-kayu - hanger
Shaman Lamp - shaman-lamp - lamp
Storage Wood Shelf - storage-wood-shelf - storage
Wood Lamp - wood-lamp - lamp
Wood Lamp Transcending - wood-lamp-transcending - lamp
Yoyo Kayu - boneka-kayu-lucu - merchandise

the images it still in json format, and i dont know how to manipulate it, im just thinking about array_value, to convert json_data after decoded to array, maybe?

Comment: Your question makes me confuse ;).  To the stdObject, if you decode json you can choose if you want to have the result as an array with keys and value, or as an object with properties. The stdClass is just an _anonymous_ object. But what is your actual problem?

Comment: @t.niese my actual problem is i dont know how to filter only one image per product, an showing them. if the primary isset on json then show the primary.. :( if you know what i mean, can you give me an example?

Comment: Just to be sure that i understand  you right. For certain products, you have more then one image in your JSON, like for your last `stdClass` in your samples. And from that you only one to have one? (could it be always the first one?)

Comment: yes, you right.. product can have more than one image and in this product page, it showing every product on database and always show the first one or show the primary image if "primary = true".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the first image or the one that has `primary`set to `true` you need to do something like this:

```
function getPrimaryImage($images) {
    //initialize the finalImage with 'null'
    $finalImage = null;

    //Iterate over all images
    foreach( $images as $image ) {

        //check if primary is set and if it is true
        if( isset($image->primary) && $image->primary ) {
            //if primary set the finalImage and exit the loop
            $finalImage = $image;
            break;
        } else if( $finalImage == null ) {
            //if primary is not set or false and the finalImage is not set, then set to the current image (first one)
            $finalImage = $image;
        }
    }

    return $finalImage;
}

foreach ($products as $prod)
{
    $prod->images = json_decode($prod->images);
    $prod->primaryImage = getPrimaryImage($prod->images);
}
```

**EDIT**
I modified your code above to show the filename:

```
foreach ($products as $prod)
{
    $prod->images = json_decode($prod->images);
    $prod->primaryImage = getPrimaryImage($prod->images);
    echo $prod->prod_name.' - '.$prod->prod_slug.' - '.$prod->cat_slug.' '.$prod->primaryImage->filename.'<br>';
}
```

You loop over the whole list having the first image set as your final result. If you find a image that has `primary` set to `true` you replace your `$finalImage` and exit the loop.

You could place this in a function that accepts `images` as parameters and return `$finalImage`  as result.

Comment: hmm what about json_decode. where i must place initiation variable and the json_decode function for images in the loop? i update the question above with sample code in my view

Comment: I updated the code, but you really should do a little bit more yourself. Creating a function out of the code i had shown you and adding it to your loop should not have been that complicated. ;)

Comment: ooooh my! i dont know how, but i solved the problem by looking at your function and create another function with array_values. your function has open my dumb head, thank you very much for your time t.niese.. i appreciate your help, i owe you :D

Comment: No problem, you need to take care when you use `json_decode` per default it returns a stdObject (i think before 5.2 it returned array by default) if you don't pass true as second parameter. So always check if you get an array or an stdObject.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a compelling reason to use JSON data? If not, simply create a new table named tbl_products_images and JOIN it with the previous JOIN.

Comment: hmm maybe because it is lot easy for me to manage product image in backend, all i need to do if image deleted or update just post it into multiple input post['images'] and update the images field. :p